# Disable OpenCV VideoWriter output

Tags: c++, opencv, stl, cout

When I create a video with OpenCV's `VideoWriter` class, it outputs something like this in the terminal :

```
Output #0, avi, to 'video.avi':
Stream #0.0: Video: mpeg4, yuv420p, 512x384, q=2-31, 12582 kb/s, 90k tbn, 24 tbc
```

I'd like to disable this but I have no idea how to do this.

Comment: That looks to me like something that ffmpeg/libav/libavcodec/x264 is writing - you get similar outputing running command-line `ffmpeg`. You may not be able to disable this without rebuilding the video libraries yourself. Do you need any other console output? If not you could pipe it to /dev/null or something.

Comment: Yes I need other console output, and this adds a lot of noise.

Answer (score 0):

"Mute" the console for a while. [Ref](https://bbs.archlinux.org/viewtopic.php?id=79378).

```
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>
int main ( int argc, char** argv )
{
    std::streambuf* cout_sbuf = std::cout.rdbuf(); // save original sbuf
    std::ofstream   fout("temp");
    std::cout<<"A\n";
    std::cout.rdbuf(fout.rdbuf()); // redirect 'cout' to a 'fout'
    std::cout<<"B\n";
    std::cout.rdbuf(cout_sbuf); // restore the original stream buffer
    std::cout<<"C\n";
    return 0;
}
```

Console output:

```
A
C
```